# Hiding custom theme functionality using capabilities

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, permissions

have spent half an hour hunting around on Google to solve this so any ideas greatly appreciated!

---

I'm using a bought theme running wp3.2 and the theme includes a few extra features Testimonials, Portfolio and Slider (they show in the admin, but aren't plugins)

I'm comfortable using `$role_objet->remove_cap();` in the funtions.php file to manage capabilities, but I'm not sure how to reference these features.

Basically I'm want to hide these menu items off for Editors.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is to hide the menu items you can make use of    `remove_menu_page` and          `remove_submenu_page` by hooking into `admin_menu`.

In order to hide certain links based on the user's role (in your case, Editor):

```
function custom_remove_menus(){

    // Get current user's data
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;

    // Check user's roles   
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        if( in_array( 'editor', $user->roles ) ) {
            // Remove menu items
            remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=news' );
            remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=news', 'post-new.php?post_type=news');
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_remove_menus' );
```

You can hover over the menus to see what the link is.

However, as noted in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page)

> Please be aware that this would not prevent a user from accessing these screens directly.  Removing a menu does not replace the need to filter a user's permissions as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If the theme is coded the right way then these features should by default only be available to users with `manage_themes` capability and that capabilty is not given to editors by default.